# How to create an object out of Vector<Class>?

Tags: java

I have a

```
Vector<Class> v = new Vector<Class>();
a.addElement(HashMap.class);
....
```

How would I create an object out of i-element of the vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
Class clazz = vector.get(i);
Object object = clazz.newInstance();
```

BTW: I wouldn't use Vector unless you have to as it is a legacy class replaced by List in Java 1.2 (1998)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`newInstance`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

`v.get(i).newInstance()`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a default constructor you can use:

```
Object o = vector.get(i).getConstructor(parameterClazzes).newInstance(parameters);
```

else

```
Object o = vector.get(i).newInstance();
```

which takes the default constructor and creates your object

---

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Integer i = Integer.class.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE).newInstance(17);
    System.out.println(i);

    String s = String.class.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("Hello");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you understand the vector class

```
class Person{
private String name;
private String lastname;
public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}
public void setLastname(String lastName){this.lastname = lastname;}
public String getName(){return name;}
public String getLastname(){ return lastname;} 
}

Vector<Person> v = new Vector<Person>(10,2);
Person objPerson = new Person();

objPerson.setName("Carl");
objPerson.setLastname("Jhonson");

v.addElement(objPerson);

System.out.println("Name: "+v.elementAt(i).getName());
System.out.println("Lastname: "+v.elementAt(i).getLastname());
```